# What's best practice to close resoures?

Tags: java, resources, autocloseable

I have a java class which has allocated resources that must be closed. I don't really know how to enforce this, my current approach is implementing the interface `AutoCloseable`, hoping that the caller calls `close()` sometimes and adding a `boolean` closed which is checked at the begin of every method and if `true`, the method throws `IllegalStateException`.

Both, that the caller has to call `close()` and that I have to check closed at the beginning of every method aren't really nice, is there some best practice to avoid this?

Comment: Your question is not clear.Make it clear and share the code snippet. It  would help us understand your problem

Comment: "Hoping that"?? Just document your classes so that you basically say that "if you don't close() this class, the behavior is undefined; please use a try-with-resources statement". Job done.

Comment: The only best practice I can think of is "make sure you do". If somebody using your code doesn't do that, well, that's their problem. The only other thing I'd add is "only close a resource you opened".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making your class implement the interface `AutoCloseable` is good approach in your case, as it allows to use it in a `try-with-resource` statement.

If for some reason you would like to limit the risk of having instances of your object not properly closed to avoid leaks, you can override the `finalize` method as next:

```
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    try {
        this.close();
    } finally {
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```

**WARNING 1:** Implementing the `finalize` method must be done with a lot of caution as it will slow down the work of the GC so you need to ensure that your code will be fast to execute.

**WARNING 2:** The `finalize` method is not necessary called so don't rely on it to `close` your object for you, it only helps to reduce the risk, users of your object still have the responsibility to `close` it properly.

Comment: Finalizer methods are not guaranteed to be *always* called, so if the resource must really *always* be closed, then this isn't a 100% solution.

Comment: My answer would be: there's no good way to *enforce* this in Java, leave it the responsibility of the user of the class to call the `close()` method. I agree that implementing `AutoCloseable` is a good idea, this should give the user at least a hint that `close()` needs to be called.

Comment: @Jasper I updated my answer to add a warning, please check again